# how to run mincraft server on linux

Tags: linux, port, tcp, minecraft

I wish to run minecraft server om my linux mint 19.0, but I have some troubles, I can start it in local, and connect by `127.0.0.1:25565` but i can't run it on my ip in inthernet, 4 example my ip is `2.60.102.109` but if I inserting this into my server.properties, I see this error in terminal:

```
arur1214@user1:~/Рабочий стол/serv$ sudo java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar bukkit1.jar nogui 
[sudo] password for arur1214: 
Loading libraries, please wait...
[16:51:58] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting minecraft server version 1.14.4
[16:51:58] [Server thread/INFO]: Loading properties
[16:51:58] [Server thread/INFO]: Default game type: SURVIVAL
[16:51:58] [Server thread/INFO]: Generating keypair
[16:51:59] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting Minecraft server on 2.60.102.109:25565
[16:51:59] [Server thread/INFO]: Using epoll channel type
[16:51:59] [Server thread/WARN]: **** FAILED TO BIND TO PORT!
[16:51:59] [Server thread/WARN]: The exception was: io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: bind(..) failed: Cannot assign requested address
[16:51:59] [Server thread/WARN]: Perhaps a server is already running on that port?
[16:51:59] [Server thread/INFO]: Stopping server
[16:51:59] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving worlds
>arur1214@user1:~/Рабочий стол/serv$
```

so, as I understand, I need to open the port, but when I added this port to virtual servers in my router as saying a lot of guides, it is doesen't helped. 
[image]
I tried to use noip dns and it's doesn't works too. so HOW TO RUN IT?

ty

Comment: Try 0.0.0.0 in server's IP config

Answer (score 2):

You can't bind to your internet IP because it's not assigned as an IP to your machine. You will need to give your internet IP to your friends to connect. As per a comment leave that option on default which is probably 0.0.0.0. In addition you should only need a forward for 25565.

Keep in mind that bukkit is different from the vanilla, default server and might work differently in some aspects. This basic functionality should be the same.

Comment: so it's works for standart minecraft server from minecraft,net, but problems is that I wish to use bukkit server. and `0.0.0.0` ip is doesen't works because i can't connect it. (can only from 127.0.1) so how to run bukkit server?

Comment: You could try to delete your server.properties file and just run the jar. It should regenerate a default one that should by default bind to every interface. Otherwise you will have to check the bukkit documentation.

Answer (score 1):

As others said:

1. You have to use `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1` : the second address is the "loopback" interface which only woirks "inside" your computer. Instead, `0.0.0.0` means "every interfaces on the system".
2. You have, then, to forward with the minecraft port (`25565`) on your ISP router to the computer running the server.

Keep in mind that, by running a service directly accessible from internet, you're exposing yourself to hacking issue ... 
If you can, do not run this on your main computer !